# Personalization of Carousel on AEM 6.3

Tags: carousel, aem, personalization

I have a requirement where we need to personalize the carousel in the home page, based on the location from where the website is accessed.

For this I have created required segments and activity and brand, and targeted to the carousel component. The issue I am facing here is that the /etc/cloudsettings/default/contexthub.kernel.js is loading after all the client libs in my project is loaded, so the carousel images are getting updated but not displayed in the form of slides, but one below the other.

Is there any event which can be captured by js and then reload the owl-carousel.js?

Could someone please suggest any fix for this?

Comment: Hey, did you found a solution for this? I've the same problem and I'm loosing my mind trying to capture some event to make the carousel work again.